# Слияние git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Какие условия надо соблюдать, чтобы команда `git merge` не создала конфликт?
Какие замены считаются зелеными, а какие красными?

Comment: Не должно быть изменений в одних и тех же файлах в одних и тех же строках

Comment: @ArchDemon, при использовании стратегий `ours` или `theirs` это не имеет значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Документация https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github  говорит о том, что ошибка возникает, когда вносят разные изменения в одну и ту же строку одного и того же файла в разных ветвях вашего Git-репозитория.